# Filter with Multiple Parameters in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing a month by month calculation of payments made, and I am having a problem with getting a correct filter.  Here is the written logic I'm looking for:

sum(payments WHEN EITHER plannedPaymentDate meets criteria X and Y AND executionDate doesn't exist OR executionDate meets criteria X and Y)

I think I'm having a problem with order of operations in regards to the parentheses inside the filter.  Here is the filter I currently have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(payments[(((plannedPaymentDate/@year = $year and plannedPaymentDate/@month = $month) and not(executionDate/@date)) or (executionDate/@year = $year and executionDate/@month = $month))]/amount/co_costprice/@anglosaxon_amount)"/>
```

I'm aware of the fact that it's large and unweildy, but each Item I'm looping over has multiple payments with potentially multiple dates and I'm trying to sum all of those payments that meet this criteria.

The issue is I have a payment for September 2019 that has a planned date then, but also has an execution date of December 2019, so the month of september should be blank but it is not, it is showing the payment amount of the planned date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(payments[
   ( ( ( plannedPaymentDate/@year = $year 
         and plannedPaymentDate/@month = $month
       ) 
       and not(executionDate/@date)
     ) 
     or ( executionDate/@year = $year 
          and executionDate/@month = $month
        )
  )
  ]/amount/co_costprice/@anglosaxon_amount)"/>
```

You haven't shown your XML source, but you say there are "multiple payment dates", and that suggests to me that in the first two conditions, you're not specifying that both conditions must be satisfied by the same `plannedPaymentDate`. So I suspect it should be

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(payments[
    ( plannedPaymentDate[@year = $year and @month = $month] 
       and not(executionDate/@date)
    ) 
    or executionDate[@year = $year and @month = $month]   
  ]/amount/co_costprice/@anglosaxon_amount)"/>
```

(I love the idea of cost prices being reckoned in anglo-saxon currency...)